# ArcGIS Pro Import Metadata with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, metadata

I'm looking for a similar functionality as this tool: [Import Metadata](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/import-metadata.htm) in ArcGIS Pro. I am upgrading some of our older scripts and I can't seem to find a similar tool or even one that could do something somewhat similar.

Does ArcGIS Pro have any ArcPy options for this at 2.6 (which I am currently using)?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?

Comment: @PolyGeo 2.6, probably 2.6.1 next week or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is discussed in the documentation here:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/metadata/migrating-from-arcmap-to-arcgis-pro.htm

I just use a simple wrapper:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import metadata as md

def pro_import_metadata(source_metadata:str, import_type:str, target_metadata:str, enable_automatic_updates:bool):  
    target_item_md = md.Metadata(target_metadata)
    target_item_md.importMetadata(source_metadata,import_type)

    if enable_automatic_updates:
        target_item_md.metadata_sync_option = 'ALWAYS'
        target_item_md.reload()
    target_item_md.save()
```

Do note that the  Import_Type strings has changed from Desktop.

Comment: This works fantastic thank you!

Comment: So for the impossibly ignorant...how does this work, and could it be adapted to take parameters and be used flexibly in a model?